# How can I parse []int JSON data in Go?

Tags: go

I try parse JSON data include integer array. But, I can't get integer array.

```
package main
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Anything struct {
    A []int `json:"a"`
}

func main() {
    s := "{a:[1,2,3]}"

    var a Anything
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &a)
    fmt.Println(a.A)
}
```

I got empty array.

```
[]
```

How can I get `[1, 2, 3]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{a:[1,2,3]}` is not valid JSON. Object keys must be double-quoted. Changing it like this works as expected:

`s := "{\"a\":[1,2,3]}"`

https://play.golang.org/p/qExZAeiRJy

Answer (score 1):

You have an invalid JSON. You should replace it, for example like this: `s := [{"a":[1,2,3]}]` or maybe like this `s := "[{\"a\":[1,2,3]}]"`.

You can edit your code to something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)


type Anything struct {
    A []int `json:"a"`
}


func main() {
    // note here: `[{"a":[1,2,3]}]`
    // or: s := "[{\"a\":[1,2,3]}]"
    s := `[{"a":[1,2,3]}]`

    var a []Anything
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &a)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Output:

```
[{[1 2 3]}]
```

You can run it on https://play.golang.org/p/H4GupGFpfP